# TypeScript intersection with generic type, and using Partial

Tags: typescript

I have a pretty tricky TypeScript issue with generics and partial.

A playground for this issue is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEkDKEHQDwAqAfKgN7CqWoDOA9gLZQBcNEM4A5gNwVUAmuBCwI8AvsGAQAngAc0AQSQQQtMIRIBeMqmlyWAcgCqABQAi8ggFEA+pgIXL+rqhkIpAG1oI+LYwhjKCO7qqKI8wEiq1BCocLS0qFrqABTgIDju2LjMqAQAlIkk5FSokWDRrNksWDj4xInadIwGcbT6ADSoAjgsaRlZ0KE8JWUVfCDUrhBIABYNycjKqiyKS2rEBRpFvCWUAPR7XQlNUBAznDuhEiUwpwCuMGBk0dmd45O4s2HA36CQsIgUKgALJSABC-jIlygAA82AhTIIWNF2GBuD8JKMYgAjSFJYipMDpEBBAY5fKFKEjKIxUgvaBvCZTL4NVqEVAAMhB4P8RGSpFQADphX0SZlalBOrD4Yieqh9CcuoJ9KE8sMqJd3syZvydLIckYzA5bPYrB0XG5PN4WALpTAEUj5bMEGioHwVaJVerKLcIA8ngL6ZKukzPnNvuI-tB4Mg0OhQWSqVQwAhmqxUejI1jULiAF7zTbbanlWmVBkhj7TcMNXEwPDxqRkvkClNp-T0WgwD1qy6jWjuKCCzwcZJBxmV2Z5H5AA)

I will explain the issue using React terminology, although it has nothing to do with React directly.

There's a custom React hook, that basically creates a reducer, using `useReducer`, and it contains some common properties, along with a generic `data` property.

Let's pretend this is the hook:

```
interface IState<T> {
    some: string;
    data: T;
}

type Action<T> = { type: 'UPDATE_STATE'; payload: Partial<T> };

const foo = <T>(initalState: T) => {
    const state: IState<T> = { some: 'foo', data: initalState };
    const dispatch = (action: Action<T>) => {
        // do something
    }

    return {state, dispatch};
};
```

In addition, there's another custom hook, that actually extends the first one by adding additional common properties to the state reducer:

```
interface MyBar {
    extraData: string;
}

const bar = <T>(initialState: T) => {
    const {state, dispatch} = foo<T & MyBar>({ ...initialState, extraData: 'some data' });
    
    return { state, dispatch };
}
```

Now, a typical usage would be:

```
const baz = () => {
    const { state, dispatch } = bar<IMyState>({ name: 'mor' });
    console.log(state, dispatch)
}
```

So in `baz`, my state object will be:

```
{
 "extraData": "some data",
 "some": "foo",
 "data": {
  "name": "mor"
 }
}
```

So far so good. Now I want to do the following change:

```
const bar = <T>(initialState: T) => {
    const {state, dispatch} = foo<T & MyBar>({ ...initialState, extraData: 'some data' });
    
    **dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_STATE', payload: { extraData: 'changed' } });**
    return { state, dispatch };
}
```

And I get:

```
Type '{ extraData: "changed"; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T & MyBar>'.(2322)
input.ts(7, 42): The expected type comes from property 'payload' which is declared here on type 'Action<T & MyBar>'
```

I am not sure why that happens, since `bar` passes the generic type alongside with the extra data, I'd expect that `foo` would be able to allow it.

I'd appreciate any advice!

Comment: should you not be using `|` instead of `&` in this case?

Comment: `foo<T | MyBar>({ ...initialState, extraData: 'some data' })` fixed the issue for me, but need to understand the context more deeper, if it has any business implications

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar unfortunatly this is not the case, `|` will not assure that I have keys from both extended and generic payloads, it can be either, but not both.

Comment: In `baz` state object should be `{ data: { extraData: string, name: string }, …}`. Notice `extraData` is nested in `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is unable to make any assumptions about assignability in this case because `T` is not infered to any type. It is like a pandora box.

Consider this example:

```js
interface IState<T> {
  some: string;
  data: T;
}

type Action<T> = { type: 'UPDATE_STATE'; payload: Partial<T> };

const foo = <T,>(initalState: T) => {
  const state = { some: 'foo', data: initalState };
  const dispatch = (action: Action<T>) => { }

  return { state, dispatch };
};

interface MyBar {
  extraData: string;
}

const bar = <T extends Record<string, unknown>,>(initialState: T) => {
  const { state, dispatch } = foo({...initialState, extraData: 'some data' });
  let x: Partial<T>
  let y: { extraData: string; }

  x = y // error
  y = x // error


  // TS is unable to make any assumptions about T
  dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_STATE', payload: { extraData: 's' } })
  return { state, dispatch };
}

const baz = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = bar({ name: 'mor', extraData: 's' });
  dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_STATE', payload: { extraData: 's' } })
  console.log(state, dispatch)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUx0gHgCoB8yA3gFDLIDOA9gLYQBcVYUoA5gNznIAm2cTPFwC%20pUmACeABxQBBBGGDUQ%20IgF4SySTKYByAKoAFACKy8AUQD66PGfO6OyKXAkAbanB5NDcKIriuqsjCXKQIypRgyDDU1Mga%20AA0BAAUoMBYrpjYjMh4AJTxRGQU4SCRzDnxmjT0ejHUuom8-EzpmdmQwVylEVE8wJTOYAgAFtUpiIrKTPLTKoSFasXBYhRQEGAArlAgNViQzQND2GPdpCFioJCwiCgAshIAQr4k3BAAHixwxq3MrCBOBcxGUKgAjV4JPDIT6QEA8SjIABKEHCUB4OEiALYzS2IAA1iBqAB3EAEZJpEAZYABTq5ApFN69cpRYiVQ68QbDM7CaoNFLEAB0wvaNKyBwgzVhUB%20f10tRQfCwumC%20R6yFcm2QH28vn8gUI3E1UQkTDZ0tlWCYWPYjlEFA%201QkyAA9C6YVAoNQoNxnRpHW6PV6fRRA3h0MhBsg8XAwZqtHFaHB8Sg4CBnXBKJQtrQpPNEbHqFsonhuMduaMBVppLkDCY7NZbBYmk4XO5PGaYV8Zb8rch5SrecJ8twNttdvsckcuadxpdRGE%20sgIQAvCZLYrcUGs9mSzknEZz6oQqBVkBwOr92jelsW3sCfuUQdqsszw9V7S1oymCyNuwt5w3A8LxNDvOUn2CVUtwiahNUFdw2BSSIp33CsR2EIA)

I'm talking about this part of the code:

```js
  let x: Partial<T>
  let y: { extraData: string; }

  x = y // error
  y = x // error
```

`x` an `y` are not assignable to each other. What if `T` is this object `{ name: string }` - then this behavior is unsafe. Because these object have nothing in common.

I know, that when you call `bar` TS is able to infer the type but remember we are not in calling phase..

Further more, the main problem is in static `extraData` property. It should be also parametrized with generic parameter.

Consider this example:

```js
interface IState<T> {
  some: string;
  data: T;
}

type Action<T> = { type: 'UPDATE_STATE'; payload: Partial<T> };

const foo = <T,>(initalState: T) => {
  const state = { some: 'foo', data: initalState };
  const dispatch = (action: Action<T>) => { }
  return { state, dispatch };
};

interface MyBar {
  extraData: string;
}

const bar = <T, U>(initialState: T, extraData: U) => {
  const { state, dispatch } = foo({ ...initialState, ...extraData });

  dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_STATE', payload: { ...extraData } })
  return { state, dispatch };
}

const baz = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = bar({ name: 'mor' }, { extraData: 's' });
  dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_STATE', payload: { extraData: 's' } })
  console.log(state, dispatch)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUx0gHgCoB8yA3gFDLIDOA9gLYQBcVYUoA5gNznIAm2cTPFwC%20pUmACeABxQBBBGGDUQ%20IgF4SySTKYByAKoAFACKy8AUQD66PGfO6OyKXAkAbanB5NDcKIriuqsjCXKQIypRgyDDU1Mga%20AA0BAAUoMBYrpjYjMh4AJTxRGQU4SCRzDnxmjT0ejHUuom8-EzpmdmQwVylEVE8wJTOYAgAFtUpiIrKTPLTKoSFasXB3FAQYACuUCA1WJDNA0PYY92kIWKgkLCIKACyEgBCviTcEAAeLHDGrcysIJxzmIyhUAEYvBJ4Zr6VLtYABTq5KHID5fH5YJj6JbFbggqLESoHXiDYanYTVBopAkAOlpcIR%20wgzVp1NRUG%20-GC%20VCFCOpNGVK00lyBhMdmstgsTScLncniYNNpbI5WGCXLWG22uwJkRyhxJJ3GF1EYT6yHBAC8JtjXr1yvjCUziccRkbquCoIKQHA6shdLRqFBdMFmgTleiBH7KMHhNzuHzDYLtCKjKYLBK7NLnG4PF5NOHfrpo2rY7iItRXBBqe42CldUSE678kCgA)

Answer (score 0):

Look at below code:

```
const {state, dispatch} = foo<T & MyBar>({ ...initialState, extraData: 'some data' });
dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_STATE', payload: { extraData: 'changed' } });
```

You must passing `Action<T & MyBar>` to `dispatch` but you sent only `MyBar` type! So you have two options:

Change `&` to `|` if you want to send only `extraData: 'changed'` as your parameter or add `...initialState` as a parameter too like this:

```
dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_STATE', payload: { ...initialState, extraData: 'changed' } });
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=25&ssc=92&pln=25&pc=5#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEkDKEHQDwAqAfKgN7CqWoDOA9gLZQBcNEM4A5gNwVUAmuBCwI8AvsGAQAngAc0AQSQQQtMIRIBeMqmlyWAcgCqABQAi8ggFEA%20pgIXL%20rqhkIpAG1oI%20LYwhjKCO7qqKI8wEiq1BCocLS0qFrqABTgIDju2LjMqAQAlIkk5FSokWDRrNksWDj4xInadIwGcbT6ADSoAjgsaRlZ0KE8JWUVfCDUrhBIABYNycjKqiyKS2rEBRpFvCWUAPR7XQlNUBAznDuhEiUwpwCuMGBk0dmd45O4s2HA36CQsIgUKgALJSABC-jIlygAA82AhTIIWNF2GBuD8JKMYgAjSFJYipMDpEBBAY5fKFKEjKIxUgvaBvCZTL4NVqEVAAMhB4P8RGSpFQADphX0SZlalBOrD4Yieqh9CcuoJ9KE8sMqJd3syZvydLIckYzA5bPYrB0XG5PN4WALhYLRaSJVK4TAEUj5bMEGioHwVaJVerKLcIA8ngL6ZKukzPnNvuI-tB4Mg0OhQWSqVQwAhmqxUej41jULiAF7zTbbanlWmVBlRj7TWMNXEwPCpqRkvkCrM5-T0WgwP1qy6jWjuKCCzwcZIRxn12Z5H5AA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although this not quite correct in this case. For the first reamark, please note that `bar` uses `foo`, so for `foo` the passed generic shouldn't be aware of any other interface.
As for the second, changing `&` to `|` is also incorrect, both technically and conspetually, since the payload should contain both, all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Poking at the underlying types reveals a slightly more verbose type error:

```
const bar = <T>(initialState: T) => {
    const {state, dispatch} = foo<T & MyBar>({ ...initialState, extraData: 'some data' });
    
    type Payload = Parameters<typeof dispatch>[0] extends Action<infer T> ? T : never
    const payload: Payload = { extraData: 'changed' };
    //    ^^^^^^^
}
```

```
Type '{ extraData: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T & MyBar'.
  Type '{ extraData: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ extraData: string; }'.(2322)
```

What I think is happening is that typescript is trying to warn about a possibility to make nonsensical type combinations, such as this:

```
bar(10).state.data.toFixed()
```

`state` now has a type `IState<number & MyBar>`, so the `toFixed()` call compiles, but since `data` is actually an object it throws an exception at runtime.

Unfortunately this doesn't really answer your question since I was unable to find any way to constrain `T` to make it compile.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42200) and also [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69084440/15005758) it is a typescript design limitation

So the only way I see is to use type assertion, something like this

```
const bar = <T>(initialState: T) => {
    const {state, dispatch} = foo<T & MyBar>({ ...initialState, extraData: 'some data' });
    const createPayload = (state: Partial<MyBar>) => state as T & MyBar;
    
    dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_STATE', payload: createPayload({ extraData: 'changed' }) });
    return { state, dispatch };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the spreading notation does not result in a type that is a simple union of the two (or more) source types.

```
type SpreadTwoObj<O1, O2> = Omit<O1, keyof O2> & O2

type A = { a: number, b: string };
type B = { b: number, c: string };
declare const a: A;
declare const b: B;

type C1 = A & B; // just a union
type C2 = SpreadTwoObj<A, B>;
const c1: C1 = { ...a, ...b }; // error
const c2: C2 = { ...a, ...b };
```

Then imagine that the first type is not an object literal.

```
type U1 = SpreadTwoObj<{ [K in string]: number }, { a: string }>;
const u1: U1 = { a: 'aa' } // error
```

It is because `Omit<{ [K: string]: number; }, "a">` does not really eliminate the key "a". (`Exclude<string, 'a'>` is still `string`). This is the limitation of TypeScript. Compare with example above:

```
type U2 = SpreadTwoObj<{ [K in 'a']: number }, { a: string }>;
const u2: U2 = { a: 'aa' } // works
```

The generic function `<T>(initialState: T) => any` that you have allows having such an ambiguous object type for the argument. Nothing can prohibit it. In your case the function `foo({ ...initialState, extraData: 'some data' })` returns `dispatch` of type `(action: Action<T & { extraData: string }>) => void`. Let `T = { [K in string]: number }`. What is the type `T & { extraData: string }` then? It is very unsound type:

```
type T = { [K in string]: number };
type D = T & { extraData: string };

const d1: D = { extraData: 'changed' }; // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
const d2: D = { extraData: 1 }; // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

That is why your example will never work unless hard code type assuming. I would do something like this although it looks mess:

```
const bar = <T>(initialState: T) => {
    const { dispatch } = foo({ ...initialState, extraData: 'some data' });

    (dispatch as (action: Action<{
        extraData: string;
    }>) => void)({ type: 'UPDATE_STATE', payload: { extraData: 'changed' } });
    return { dispatch };
}
```

(I rid off `state` from the example because it is irrelevant.)

[Supporting playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAymBOECGATAKgdwPYHkBGAVgDw4CMANFDgEwB8UAvFQLYCWwJFUA1hCFgDMqdKADJhAKAmhIUAIKMoAbyhIAXFAB2AV2Z4I8Sng0BnYPFaaA5lAC+AbmnhoAIUUrjW3fsNQAxqbmljYOEigQfgA2SIj+WJpmqhpyjuFRMdB+8YmeLo5OsgDCpIoK4nlQAPSVUATaiUhQ2pqs8QXQhdSKcIiomLiERHKULrSOWQnA-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-sAmaKIhSDHqeyT0fEkF4QwBFESRnHmigHYmFgzAQMAGbBBxxG2FInGIMA2jwM6KjkSYlHUaE0HolAeAxIoSEoWBkToWGWFQLh+HKKJpGJPJFFhspiiwVgiGXEsOmsGhGEQJQo4puOxp8QJsZpvmOH5JxiEKUpGZrlAtFMZojEnsxhGcZxnmphOLrWI4nE6qx9AAG5YKwKA4Q5nbODe96Ps+b4fs++KUL+-6ASgGgBsmqXplmOZ5nYdhBWZUkyXJsZWVREUqRIQA)